# Could Slither (2006) be considered canon in the MCU?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, reference, guardians-of-the-galaxy, slither

In the scene with the Collector in *Guardians of the Galaxy*, one of the tanks in the room contains The Long One and several of the Slugs from *Slither*. This is clearly an Easter egg, but it begs the question, since the organisms from Slither exist in the Marvel universe, could that mean the events of Slither occurred in it as well?

Comment: If we consider slither as canon, we would be living in a world where 3 vampires are huddled together somewhere, Nick Fury starred as Mace Wundu and Vincent Vega and Cap is gonna be shocked when he watches star wars sometime and so on... If we consider them as references, MCU is saved... :D Besides they could just be considered as just ordinary slugs that the collector collected...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that's more a case of James Gunn referencing his earlier work (as well as other stuff), and not canon, after all, they didn't "win" in Slither, the parasite survived, leaving the possibility of a sequel (unless Taneleer Tivan stepped in and whisked it away), so all life on Earth is left under threat.

After all, the Collectors museum contains loads of [stuff](http://www.slashfilm.com/guardians-of-the-galaxy-easter-eggs/2/), Cosmo the Space Dog, Howard the Duck, a Dark Elf, a Chitauri Soldier, the Tesseract, Adam Warlock's cocoon (maybe), Beta-Ray Bill (possibly).

Just because another film is referenced doesn't mean that all of cinematic history is now part of the same universe, so no, Nick Fury is not also Mace Windu etc, it probably follows more along the Tarantino [rules](https://www.ifc.com/2015/02/tarantino-guide-shared-universe).

Comment: But everything else in the Collector's museum is in the marvel comics

Comment: And it’s likely that is not Howard, but another denizen of Duckworld. http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Howard_the_Duck_(Earth-791021)

Comment: Everything else is in the Marvel universe, safe to say that Gunn was just being self referential and having a little fun.

Comment: I just want a slither sequel

Comment: In *Infinity War* Tobias from **Arrested Development** is in one of his tubes but that won't make AD part of MCU, sadly